# How does a web reference know what address to use?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, asmx

I have to make a call to a web service from inside a new C# class library project.  The web service is not accessible to me yet (different geographic location and closed network until release).  I do have the WSDL for it however and have added a Web Reference in my new class library project to the WSDL.

My problem here is that I do not see where I can configure the service address that the WSDL is based on.  It's fine developing against the WSDL stub for now, but when I release it to the other development centre, they will need to be able to set the correct address for their service so that my service call into it works.

Is there a common practice here?  i.e. a config file entry that I can add or something?

Comment: FYI, web references use the legacy ASMX web service technology. You should use a Service Reference instead. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Yes, I know this John but my overlord Development Managers in the parent company live a Tardis that is stuck on reverse and I have to do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added the web reference using VS, it will automatically creating a corresponding setting in your .config file.

You can also view / modify this in Settings.settings.

N.B. by default VS sets this setting to generate a default value (which is based on the original value you use to add the reference, I believe and it gets buried somewhere in a generated code file). You can disable this by viewing the project's Properties --> Settings, highlighting the WSDL setting and then in the Properties tab (docked window) set GenerateDefaultValueInCode = False.

Once deployed, the WSDL location can be updated by modifying the relevant .config file value.

---

EDIT: the Web Reference URL Behaviour property should be set to Dynamic.

Comment: An example would be helpful

Comment: The class library project doesn't have a config file and there is nothing under settings either.  I'm using VS 2012 if that matters.

Comment: So, add an app.config, add the web reference again, then copy from the code that got added to the app.config into the config file of the calling application.

Comment: I did try that already - adding the web service reference does not add anything to the App.config file.

Comment: Check the Web Reference properties (docked window). Ensure that URL Behaviour is set to Dynamic.

Comment: It is set to Dynamic Tom.

Comment: I added a service reference instead (to compare app.config updating behaviour) and doing that does not add an entry to the app.config file either!  I wonder is this a limitation of VS 2012 and/or that it is in a class library project.

Comment: I just created a new Class Library project in VS2010. Adding the Web Reference actually created the app.config file with the relevant <configuration> settings. I'm out of ideas - sorry!

Comment: I've discovered that the act of adding the reference (service reference or web reference) to the WSDL instead of an actual service results in the config file not being updated.

Comment: Based on the above, I created a stub service based on the WSDL and added a web reference and the bits required appear in the app.config now.  The basic WSDL reference would need manual creation etc I guess.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Look for endpoint node in your app.config, change URL for different environments

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>      
       ...
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="#URL#"
            binding="xxx" bindingConfiguration="xxx"
            contract="xxx" name="xxx" />
```

Comment: he has wsdl file, you can still add service ref and point it to local file that will create everything necessary

Comment: I agree that is what he _should_ do, but he's not doing it. He added a web reference instead.

Comment: I've been instructed to use a web reference - I've no choice.  If I could, I would of course use a service reference and this topic would not have graced the StackOverflow board. :)